# Tikz angles library: draw arc while setting anchor

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-angles

I am using the Tikz library angles to draw an arc between two edges. My goal is to create this:

[image: Goal]

However, I don't know how to set the anchors for the \pic command. I set it for the edges, but (logically), this doesn't give the desired result:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle] (n3) at (0,0) {3};
\node[draw,circle] (n4) at (1,0.5) {4};
\node[draw,circle] (n5) at (1,-0.5) {5};
\draw[->] (n3) to (n4);
\draw[->] (n3) to (n5);

\pic[draw]{angle=n5--n3--n4};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Current]

How can i set the anchors in the \pic command? The following didn't work:

```
\pic[draw]{angle=n5--n3.east--n4};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. The solution is to create an additional coordinate east of the node, and draw things from there:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle] (n3) at (0,0) {3};
\coordinate[right=0mm of n3]  (n3e);
\node[draw,circle] (n4) at (1,0.5) {4};
\node[draw,circle] (n5) at (1,-0.5) {5};
\draw[->] (n3e) to (n4);
\draw[->] (n3e) to (n5);

\pic[draw,angle radius=2mm]{angle=n5--n3e--n4};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,angles,arrows.meta,quotes,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{through}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,circle] (n3) at (0,0) {3};
    \node[draw,circle] (n4) at (1,0.5) {4};
    \node[draw,circle] (n5) at (1,-0.5) {5};
    \draw[->] (n3.east) to (n4);
    \draw[->] (n3.east) to (n5);
%   \pic[draw]{angle=n5--n3--n4};
\draw[thick,red] ([shift=(-15:0.5cm)]0,0) arc (-15:15:0.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i am trying to use the angles library. The reason for this is that i don't want to manually put in any coordinates. Also, it allows me to use other features of that library.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the example under the link will help you ([Draw angle between two line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444606/draw-angle-between-two-line)). So you can define a certain radius for the angle.